# how do i get rid of the atlas error in the command line?

Tags: database, mongodb

how do i get rid of the atlas error in the command line? This appears when attempting to connect to the database.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const connectionString='mongodb+srv:
//Reina:FakePassword1@cluster0.65vzt.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

MongoClient.connect(connectionString,  (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  console.log('Connected to Database') 
})
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
ok: 0,
code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError',
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `connect` on the `client` instance, try with:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const connectionString='mongodb+srv://Reina:FakePassword1@cluster0.65vzt.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to database')
    } catch (err) {
        await client.close();
        console.log(err)
    }
}

// Connect to DB
connectDb();
```

For more, check out the official [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/#connection-guide)